# Updating form to include TOTAL for dollars and cents

Tags: javascript, forms

Have been researching for a few days for a from that can simply add the totals of the sales values and output a grand total.  Using this as a simple sales submission form.  The problem is that the form doesn't add, include or calculate the cents.

I found the form on a previous question: [How get total sum from input box values using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540751/how-get-total-sum-from-input-box-values-using-javascript)

Was wondering how could the form be updated to also include dollars and cents in the total value?

Thank-you in advanced.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. I hope my answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Skwal My apologies.  Found the form and it worked well but I wasn't sure what part of the from had to be changed in order for the form to calculate and include cents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace the `parseInt()` with `parseFloat()` so that it keeps the decimals.

Comment: Your answer did the trick.  Thank you for the response.