# in multiple input field enter the different numbers how can add automatically in javascript

Tags: javascript

in multiple input field enter the different numbers how can add automatically in javascript

how can i find sum of different input field in different numbers in javascript.

"the input field is n numbers..:" and this input fields i using the clone function

[image: like this modal]

only consider in numbers field not related for text field
 [almost this model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540751/how-get-total-sum-from-input-box-values-using-javascript)
note:but my condition is here is different name and id

how can i do ?
pleas help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `onchange` event on all inputs that are needed to be summed

```
<input class="sum" onchange="add()" />
```

and can add and place the sum into the the total input like below

```
function add(){
 total= 0;
 sum =document.getElementsByClassName("sum");
 for(a=0;a<sum.length;a++)
   {
     console.log(sum[a].value);
   total += parseInt(sum[a].value || 0);
  }
  document.getElementById("total").value = total;
}
```

**Code/Demo:**

```js
function add(){
 total= 0;
 sum =document.getElementsByClassName("sum");
 for(a=0;a<sum.length;a++)
   {
     console.log(sum[a].value);
   total += parseInt(sum[a].value || 0);
  }
  document.getElementById("total").value = total;
}
```

```html
One   <input class="sum" onchange="add()" /><br/>
Two  <input class="sum" onchange="add()" /><br/>
Three <input class="sum" onchange="add()" /><br/>
Four  <input class="sum" onchange="add()" /><br/>
Total   <input id="total"  /><br/>
```

Comment: how can use this one in different id and name ? any possible ?

Comment: @user5945137 can you explain your question again? didnt got your point :)