# Get textbox value in single/multiple

Tags: javascript, html

I have a field in my page named as "myField" Now this is dynamic So there are 2 cases i.e. it can be just 1 field as;

```
<input type="text" name="myField" />
```

OR there can be 2 fields as below;

```
<input type="text" name="myField" />
<input type="hidden" name="myField" />
```

I use the following code to access the value in JS;

```
document.forms[0].myField[0].value
```

However, this does not work if there is only 1 field (as in the first case)

How do I write dynamic JS code to handle the same? It should be cross browser compatible.

Comment: don't name form fields the same.

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
 var texts = document.getElementsByName("n");
    var sum = "";
    for( var i = 0; i < texts.length; i ++ ) {
        sum = sum + texts[i].value;
    }
    document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = sum;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="n"/>
<input type="text" name="n"/>
<p id="sum"></p>
<button id="btn"> Get Sum</button>
```

or Visit :[How get total sum from input box values using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540751/how-get-total-sum-from-input-box-values-using-javascript/37880193#37880193)

Answer (score 0):

On first glance of that particular example, it seems odd that those two fields have the same name. Normally one would expect the same name for fields that are mutually-exclusive, or that are the same type and form a list.

But you can still work with them: I wouldn't use the automatic properties, since as you've discovered they're inconsistent (`document.forms[0].myField` will be the field when there's only one, but a collection of fields with the same name if there's more than one). I'd use `querySelectorAll`:

```
var fields = document.querySelectorAll('[name="myField"]');
```

`fields` will reliably be a list. You can access the elements of that list using `fields[0]` and such, and get the length from `fields.length`.

```js
var fields = document.querySelectorAll('[name="myField"]');
for (var n = 0; n < fields.length; ++n) {
  console.log("fields[" + n + "].value: ", fields[n].value);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="myField" value="the text field"/>
<input type="hidden" name="myField" value="the hidden field"/>
```

Comment: Wouldn't `document.getElementsByName` be better?

Comment: @Tobsta: I wouldn't say "better," but it would also work, sure. Waruna posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37880776/157247) showing it.