# How to get sum of the calculated column on input

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint-2013, office365

I have tree number columns, and  create a calculated column to get the sum of the  tree inputs , but I have to click save to see change .
I'm looking to get the result on the calculated column ,when someone type or change  a number in one of the three column before pressing save.
I tried this JavaScript code :

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "You wrote: " + x;
}
```

but in my case I have 3 number columns
any idea?

Comment: Were you developing an Office add-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the solution below. You'll have to add some validation so that only numbers were allowed

```js
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("myInput");

function myFunction() {
 var total = 0;

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function (input) {
        total += +input.value;
    });

    document.getElementsByClassName("myOutput")[0].innerHTML = "The total is: " + total;
}

for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener("input", function () {
        myFunction();
    });
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
    <input type="text" class="myInput">
    <input type="text" class="myInput">
    <input type="text" class="myInput">
</form>

<div class="myOutput"></div>
```

What you do is loop through the inputs while attaching the event listener and calculating the total. there are 2 ways to do this, both implemented above.

Comment: your code work just fine , thanks 
i found this function who work just fine too :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540751/how-get-total-sum-from-input-box-values-using-javascript

Comment: how can i apply this function only on two input without using the boucle for?